# Bash - omit lines starting with a mis-spelled word (using hunspell)

Tags: bash, command-line, hunspell

I have a file `words.txt` in which each line is a word, followed by a `TAB`, followed by an integer (which represents the word's frequency). I want to generate a new file containing only those lines where the word is spelled correctly.

Using `cat words.txt | hunspell -1 -G > ok_words.txt` I can get a list of correct words, but how can I also include the remainder of each line (ie the `TAB` and the number)?

Input:

```
adwy  27
bird  10
cat   12
dog   42
erfgq 9
fish  2
```

Desired Output:

```
bird  10
cat   12
dog   42
fish  2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the `join` command:

```
$ join words.txt ok_words.txt 
bird 10
cat 12
dog 42
fish 2
```

or to preserve tabs:

```
$ join -t $'\t' words.txt ok_words.txt 
bird    10
cat 12
dog 42
fish    2
```

Comment: In a single line without a temporary file: `join words.txt <(hunspell -1 -G < words.txt)`

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. (I've combined this with @l0b0's suggestion to get `join -t $'\t' words.txt <(hunspell -1 -G < words.txt) > ok_words.txt`)